# C# OpenCV Count white spots in a image

Tags: c#, opencv

Hi I'm trying to count the number and size of white spots in this image I'm using opencv, I was able to do it with perfect circles but I can't do it with this irregular spots.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Mat train = new Mat("blob.jpg", ImreadModes.GrayScale);
    SimpleBlobDetector[] blobs;

    CircleSegment[] circles;
    Mat dst = new Mat();

    Cv2.GaussianBlur(train, dst, new OpenCvSharp.Size(5, 5), 1.5, 1.5);
    circles = Cv2.HoughCircles(dst, HoughMethods.Gradient, 1, 25, 75, 60, 1, 200);

    for (int i = 0; i < circles.Length; i++)
    {
        Cv2.Circle(dst, circles[i].Center, (int) circles[i].Radius, new Scalar(125), 2);
    }

    using (new Window("Circles", dst))
    {
        Cv2.WaitKey();
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HoughCircles you would need a large number of iterations trying out different parameters, which is probably not what you want in this case.

I don't know the specifics of your problem. For this little demo I blurred a 
 bit, filtered out all the (dark) grayish bits, as they are not really 'white' (using otsu's threshold). Then I simply applied `findContours` and drew them all. This is Java code, first thing I could get my hands on. Nevertheless, you should be able to understand and have it guide you towards a solution for your problem.

Another possible solution I can think of would be using OpenCV's feature detectors (e.g. a simple blob detector).

```
Mat gray = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(img, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Mat blur = new Mat();
Mat kernel = Mat.ones(2, 2, CvType.CV_8UC1);
Imgproc.morphologyEx(gray, blur, Imgproc.MORPH_OPEN, kernel);
Mat thresh = new Mat();
Imgproc.threshold(blur, thresh, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(thresh, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
Imgproc.drawContours(img, contours, -1, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);
```

[image]